# Scraping dynamic website with hidden elements

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs

The purpose is to scrape [booking.com](https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?ss=Copenhagen%20Denmark&checkin_year=2020&checkin_month=2&checkin_monthday=6&checkout_year=2020&checkout_month=2&checkout_monthday=9&group_adults=2&group_children=0&no_rooms=1&no_dorms=1&nflt=pri%3D1%3Bpri%3D2%3B) to get all the prices displayed. For that I'm using PhantomJS that runs the javascript code below, and then writes the content of the webpage to a local html file.

```
var url = 'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?ss=Copenhagen%20Denmark&checkin_year=2020&checkin_month=2&checkin_monthday=6&checkout_year=2020&checkout_month=2&checkout_monthday=9&group_adults=2&group_children=0&no_rooms=1&no_dorms=1&nflt=pri%3D1%3Bpri%3D2%3B';
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    fs.write('result.html', page.content, 'w');
    phantom.exit();
};

page.open(url, function() {
    page.evaluate(function() {
    });
});
```

The problem is that the prices are not read, and the result looks like this(all the filters got lost and there are some warnings and errors logged in the console)

[image: result]

Here are for example some of the elements that should've been scraped:

```
<div class="bui-price-display__value prco-inline-block-maker-helper" aria-hidden="true">
    €&nbsp;246
</div>
<span class="bui-u-sr-only">
    Preis
    €&nbsp;246
</span>
```

If this is not possible with PhantomJS, are there any alternatives? I also tried cURL but to no avail.

Comment: Have you looked at the  [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) project with headless chrome. Very useful for JS laden sites.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out!